unable to connect to raspberry pi 5 after it's sat around for a few days
I have a Raspberry Pi 5 and after it's been up for a few days I am unable to connect to it via SSH / VNC nor am I able to Ping it from my Windows laptop. I can access the Raspberry Pi with the keyboard that's physically plugged into it and from that I can see that, from the Raspberry Pi, I can connect to other machines on my LAN, but I just can't connect to the Raspberry Pi from other machines on my LAN.
Here's the output I get when I do sudo iptables -S:
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/24 -i wlan0 -m comment --comment nordvpn -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/24 -i eth0 -m comment --comment nordvpn -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i wlan0 -m connmark --mark 0xe1f1 -m comment --comment nordvpn -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -m connmark --mark 0xe1f1 -m comment --comment nordvpn -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i wlan0 -m comment --comment nordvpn -j DROP
-A INPUT -i eth0 -m comment --comment nordvpn -j DROP
-A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 10.0.0.1-10.0.0.255 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.0/24 -o wlan0 -m comment --comment nordvpn -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.0/24 -o eth0 -m comment --comment nordvpn -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o wlan0 -m mark --mark 0xe1f1 -m comment --comment nordvpn -j CONNMARK --save-mark --nfmask 0xffffffff --ctmask 0xffffffff
-A OUTPUT -o wlan0 -m connmark --mark 0xe1f1 -m comment --comment nordvpn -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -m mark --mark 0xe1f1 -m comment --comment nordvpn -j CONNMARK --save-mark --nfmask 0xffffffff --ctmask 0xffffffff
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -m connmark --mark 0xe1f1 -m comment --comment nordvpn -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o wlan0 -m comment --comment nordvpn -j DROP
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -m comment --comment nordvpn -j DROP

In particular, take note of this one:
-A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 10.0.0.1-10.0.0.255 -j ACCEPT

So, as I understand it, I'm telling iptables to whitelist any connection on any port from any IP address falling between 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.255. Is that correct? If that's the case then why can't I connect to it from my Windows 11 laptop, which has an IP address of 10.0.0.34?
It's not like the Raspberry Pi doesn't have network connectivity since, like I said, I can connect to other computers on my LAN from my Raspberry Pi.
What's also messed up is that if I restart the computer I am able to connect. It's like I'm able to connect for a few days and everything works great but then I just lose the ability to remotely connect and get it back after I reboot. Which I'd rather not do.
If I ping my Raspberry Pi's IP address (it has a static IP address of 10.0.0.140) when the issue starts manifesting itself I get this:
Pinging 10.0.0.140 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.0.0.34: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 10.0.0.34: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 10.0.0.34: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 10.0.0.34: Destination host unreachable.

That's the same output I get if I ping an IP address that doesn't exist on the LAN.
Here's what happens if I ping before the issue happens or right after a reboot that fixes the issue:
Pinging 10.0.0.140 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.0.0.140: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.140: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.140: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64
Reply from 10.0.0.140: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=64

The Raspberry Pi has a static IP of 10.0.0.140, a netmask of 24 and a gateway of 10.0.0.1 (which I can see if I click on the network status icon  in the top right and then clicking on Advanced Options -> Edit Connections... -> Wireless -> preconfigured -> IPv4 Settings).
Any ideas?
(I'm posting this here because, altho I'm willing to concede that this could be a generic Linux issue, I also can't dismiss the possibility that's a Raspberry Pi specific issue; I have similarly configured Linux EC2 instances on AWS and don't have any issues requiring reboots on those)

You've got a problem on your network that has nothing to do with the RPi.

perhaps the pi's IP address changes ... are you trying to connect using IP address or something else? Also, you haven't mentioned nordvpn in the question, but it clearly is at play with your issue

Why don't you let your router assign an address - that way your network would know about it.

Does your LAN include a router that dynamically assign IP addresses? If so, what is the range of IP addresses the DHCP server (most likely your router) uses for dynamic assignment? For example it the range of dynamic assignment is from 10.0.0.100 to 10.0.0.250 then 10.0.0.140 lies within that range and may cause a conflict if you set this IP address in your Raspberry Pi. Either set an IP address outside this range, or use the router's settings to reserve the 10.0.0.140 and bind it the MAC address of your Raspberry Pi.
